# what is an extension function?

Tags: language-agnostic, terminology

I am learning the codebase for the Flight Gear project. On their [wiki](http://wiki.flightgear.org/List_of_Nasal_extension_functions#setprop.28.29) they have a list of "extension functions" for the project's internal scripting language (called NASAL).

What is an extension function?  Is this a common term?